# I can't figure out the casting of date types and time zones

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, dsl, querydsl

I have a Java application. To search by dates, I use the following technologies: JPA, and QueryDSL. The search is like this:

```
if (nonNull(params.getPlanned_date_from()) || nonNull(params.getPlanned_date_to())) {
    predicate.and(SQLExpressions.datetrunc(DatePart.day, preorder.plannedDate)
            .between(params.getPlanned_date_from(), params.getPlanned_date_to()));
}
```

An error is:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function
> trunc_day(timestamp without time zone) does not exist    No function
> matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add
> explicit type casts.

How to set up time zone through env variables? To much to do and no enough answers in the internet about working with QueryDSL.
Please help me. There might be some thing very easy, but I don't see it.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. PostgreSQL doesn't have a function `trunc_day`, so likely you need to do some [dialect configuration](http://querydsl.com/static/querydsl/5.0.0/reference/html_single/#d0e1102) somewhere.

Comment: I'm not sure your problem is about environment variables. The error message says that the function date_trunc() does not exist for the input parameter type `timestamp with time zone`. Either, this function doesn't exist or it exists for another input parameter type and you have to cast `DatePart.day`with that type.

Comment: @Edouard the error says `trunc_day()` does not exist and indeed there is no such built in function in Postgres. There is `date_trunc()` and it does accept `timestamp with time zone`: select date_trunc('day', '2022-01-06 8:30'::timestamptz);  2022-01-06 00:00:00-08`

Comment: By the way, date-time ranges are usually best defined as Half-Open where the beginning is inclusive and the ending is exclusive. For Half-Open, do not use SQL command `BETWEEN` as it is Fully-Closed.

Comment: Thank You very much for your answers. I really understand, what happens and understand how to solve it in sql. But i don't understand how to do this, using this libs. How they like to complicate things in our project...